# EF Fluent API Mapping with 1 constant field

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

we have a SQL database setup like this

```
Table 1 Tasks
-------------
TenantId int
TaskId int
TypeId int


Table2 TaskTypes
----------------
TenantId int
TypeId int
Name varchar(100)
Language varchar(2)
```

We use the EF-fluent-api for mapping, because we have an existing database schema.

This is our mapping

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
            var mbTask = modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().ToTable("tasks");

            mbTask.HasOne(x => x.TaskType)
                .WithMany(x => x.Tasks)
                .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.TenantId, x.TypeId })
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => new { x.TenantId, x.TypeId });
            
            var mbTaskType = modelBuilder.Entity<TaskType>().ToTable("task_types");
```

This sorta works, but when you add this to TaskTypes

- TenantId = 1, TypeId = 1 , Lang = NL , Name = Test
- TenantId = 1, TypeId = 1 , Lang = FR , Name = Test(FR)

we get this exception

> The instance of entity type 'TaskType' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the same key value for {'TenantId', 'TypeId'} is
> already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
> only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider
> using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> conflicting key values.

We get this issue because we cannot add Lang to the index, because the Tasks table does not have this field.

Comment: Is TypeId a foreign key in TaskTypes?

Comment: @jao, TypeId is the PK of TaskType, and a FK in Task (together with TenantId, we have a multi-tenant database). The field LANG should be in the composite foreign key in AF, be since it is not existing in the Task table, this cannot be done

Comment: I think this is a database design fault. Adding Lang to the PK of TaskType or using unique ID's for TypeId should fix it.